# Discard tables/subqueries with nulls or empty

Tags: postgresql

I have a view in PostgreSQL like this.:

```
SELECT met1.tiempo,
    met1.pyrseg AS met1_pyrseg,
    met1.pyrhor AS met1_pyrhor,
    met2.pyrseg AS met2_pyrseg,
    met2.pyrhor AS met2_pyrhor,
    met3.pyrseg AS met3_pyrseg,
    met3.pyrhor AS met3_pyrhor
FROM      
    (SELECT meteo_hour.tstamp AS tiempo,
        avg(meteo_hour.avg_globalradiation1) AS pyrseg,
        avg(meteo_hour.avg_globalradiation2) AS pyrhor
    FROM dw.meteo_hour
    WHERE meteo_hour.meteo = 0
    GROUP BY meteo_hour.tstamp) met1,

    (SELECT meteo_hour.tstamp AS tiempo,
        avg(meteo_hour.avg_globalradiation1) AS pyrseg,
        avg(meteo_hour.avg_globalradiation2) AS pyrhor
    FROM dw.meteo_hour
    WHERE meteo_hour.meteo = 25
    GROUP BY meteo_hour.tstamp) met2,

    (SELECT meteo_hour.tstamp AS tiempo,
        avg(meteo_hour.avg_globalradiation1) AS pyrseg,
        avg(meteo_hour.avg_globalradiation2) AS pyrhor
    FROM dw.meteo_hour
    WHERE meteo_hour.meteo = 35
    GROUP BY meteo_hour.tstamp) met3

WHERE met1.tiempo = met2.tiempo AND met3.tiempo = met1.tiempo
```

The problem appears when one of the 3 subqueries fails. As there is one subquery with no values, then the last WHERE fails because one of the comparisons is against null values.

How can I discard a subquery when there are null values or is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `FULL JOIN`. With some other improvements you will get this:

```
SELECT tiempo, met1_pyrseg, met1_pyrhor,
               met2_pyrseg, met2_pyrhor,
               met3_pyrseg, met3_pyrhor
FROM (
    SELECT tstamp AS tiempo,
           avg(avg_globalradiation1) AS met1_pyrseg,
           avg(avg_globalradiation2) AS met1_pyrhor
    FROM dw.meteo_hour
    WHERE meteo = 0
    GROUP BY tstamp) met1
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT tstamp AS tiempo,
           avg(avg_globalradiation1) AS met2_pyrseg,
           avg(avg_globalradiation2) AS met2_pyrhor
    FROM dw.meteo_hour
    WHERE meteo = 25
    GROUP BY tstamp) met2 USING (tiempo)
FULL JOIN (
    SELECT tstamp AS tiempo,
           avg(avg_globalradiation1) AS met3_pyrseg,
           avg(avg_globalradiation2) AS met3_pyrhor
    FROM dw.meteo_hour
    WHERE meteo = 35
    GROUP BY tstamp) met3 USING (tiempo)
ORDER BY tiempo;
```

Comment: Ooooohhhh very, very, very thanks.

Sometimes you get an idea into your head, and the solution is as simple as this.

Solved